# Ruby: Mongoid Criteria Selector to SQL Query

Tags: ruby, mongodb, postgresql, mongoid, sequel

As part of my bachelor's thesis I'm building a Microservice using Postgres which would in part replace an existing part of an application using MongoDB. Now to change as little as possible at the moment on the client side I was wondering if there was an easy way to translate a `Mongoid::Criteria` to an SQL query (assuming all fields are named the same, of course), without having to write a complete parser myself. Are there any gems out there that might support this?

Any input is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for this : https://github.com/stripe/mosql.
I don't dig it but it seems to work for what you need :

"MoSQL imports the contents of your MongoDB database cluster into a PostgreSQL instance, using an oplog tailer to keep the SQL mirror live up-to-date. This lets you run production services against a MongoDB database, and then run offline analytics or reporting using the full power of SQL."